# Is there an iOS equivalent to navigator.share to trigger the native share function?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

We want to trigger the native share function from our mobile site (so people can see their preferred sharing channels).

All the information I can find around this topic is quite dated, so I'm wondering whether there's a more recent API that's available on iOS safari (etc) to trigger the native share function from within a web app (or PWA).

Comment: I've found nothing either... i guess you should place whatsapp / email buttons programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

To implement that share functionality you can use [Web Share API](https://w3c.github.io/web-share/).

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS. Discussed here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302475/can-i-share-a-file-with-web-share-api-on-safari/66126240#66126240